# How to access extra FORM fields NOT in the model?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

I'm working on an admin form for updating user accounts. I want to provide the option for the admin to assign a new password. So I need to add 2 fields to form, Password and ConfirmPassword. Password works fine since it is in my User model, but the second field, ConfirmPassword, is not available when the form is submitted.

Here is the method in my Controller that receives the form data:

```
@PostMapping("/users/updateUser")
public ModelAndView updateUser (@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/users");
}
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this. One idea I had was to create a DTO that has all the fields including the extra one then use a ModelMapper to transfer the data to a User object. But this seems like overkill.

Is there a cleaner way to accept form fields that are not in the User model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a Transient field in your model class. The reason behind using Transient variable is that it will not participate in persisting (it won't create a field in the database table). You can use this field for check purpose.

```
@Transient
private String confirmPassword;

// Getter/Setters
```